# Are 2 references to an object == to each other?

Tags: java, tdd

I have a method, move(xSteps, ySteps), which takes a point and moves it according to the parameters on the method by increasing or decreasing x and y.

But when the xSteps and ySteps are both 0, I want to store the moved point (which didn't actually move) in the same memory location as the original point since the x and y value should be the same.

The move method is below

```
public Point move(int xSteps, int ySteps) {
    Point p;
    Point p2;
    if (xSteps == 0 && ySteps == 0) {
        p = new Point(x, y);
        p2 = p
        return p2;
    } else {
        p2 = new Point(x + xSteps, y + ySteps);
    }
    return p2;
}
```

However when i run this test,

```
moved = point.move(0,0);

        Assertions.assertTrue(p == moved);
```

It returns false, but it should be true. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p == moved` tests whether `p` and `moved` reference the same object.

Since the `move()` method always returns a `new Point()` this test will fail with your current implementation of the `move()` method.

If you *want to store the moved point (which didn't actually move) in the same memory location as the original point* then you need to change your move method to

```
public Point move(int xSteps, int ySteps) {
    if (xSteps == 0 && ySteps == 0) {
        return this;
    } else {
        return new Point(x + xSteps, y + ySteps);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `==` checks if objects *p* and *moved* are the same object. Since you created a new object (`p = new Point`), *moved* will not be the same object even if it has the same values.

If you want to compare values, you can use equals().
So: `Assertions.assertTrue( p.equals(moved) );`

Comment: Assuming equals is overridden correctly.